# How to position 3 text items horizontally in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I have WPF application with layout where I should put 3 text items (ends with _Ch1, _Ch2, _Ch3) horizontally. I did it in a way you could see in a picture attached. As you can see, the 3 text items are in the center of horizontal area, but I need to put them in a way that is similar to 3 columns that is first text item should be moved to left, second one should leave in the center, and third one should be moved to right.

[image]

The code is as following:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedEventPhotoList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>

public List<string> SelectedEventPhotoList
{
    get { return _selectedEventPhotoList; }
    set
    {
        if (Equals(value, _selectedEventPhotoList))
            return;

        _selectedEventPhotoList = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedEventPhotoList);
    }
}
```

How to do it?

Comment: the uniform grid is already doing that for you, however the items control has not stretched the grind to fill its content area, try setting the HorizontalContentAlignment to stretch

Comment: What is your Items control inside and what is it's content alignment set to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `ItemTemplate`:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedEventPhotoList}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

#### Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: The "Stretch" is not needed. I need to add VerticalAlignment="Center" to TextBlock and that's it. Thanks.